# Send file to url with browser

Tags: http, post, file-upload, browser, multipartform-data

If I wish to get from a resource with cURL I can use this:

```
curl "http://myresource/path"
```

and I can also try it in a browser by typing http://myresource/path in the url field.

If I wish to send a file as well I can do it with cURL like this:

```
curl -F "file=@C:\myfilepath/file.doc" "http://myresource/path"
```

but how can I post a file through a browser's url field?

Answer (score 0):

I think the command is:

```
 $ curl -X POST -d @myfilename http://myresource/path
```

If the form you're trying to submit uses the type 'multipart/form-data', then and only then you must use the -F type. If not, you need use -d which then causes a posting with the type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'.

Example script received file:

```
<!-- The data encoding type, enctype, MUST be specified as below -->
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="__URL__" method="POST">
    <!-- MAX_FILE_SIZE must precede the file input field -->
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
    <!-- Name of input element determines name in $_FILES array -->
    Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: there is no problem with the code provided. And you didn't answer the question here.

Comment: Sorry, Maybe I do not understand your question. You need send file with curl? because to put a file, the URL should this able to receive or send.

Comment: no the file is sent fine with curl. But is it possible to use a browser for this instead of curl?

Comment: I believe that the browser will not load alone, you need to call a script or url.

I added a sample script in php to receive a file and save it in a folder.